# Is using die frowned upon / bad?

Tags: php, ajax, structure, die

I'm currently developping my first proper php website, and I find myself, especially when writing ajax/php pages, writing procedural codes which look like this:

```
//sanitize input
foo();

//handle request
bar();

//sends reply
echo json_encode( $result );

die;

function foo(){...}
function bar(){...}
```

where my code is clearly separated into a procedural step by step part at the top of the page, and a list of function at the end.

I like using die; in that context since it provides a clear cut between the two parts of the code, but I'm wondering if it is frowned upon for some reason.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: off topic, because purely opinion-based. personally i'd have to say: why don't you store your function in single files and include them? and why don't you group related functions into classes?

Comment: This is a valid "what's the best practice" kind of question in my opinion. @FranzGleichmann

Comment: Well a lot of ajax call only achieve a small task, for instance adding/checking/deleting from database. Therefore it appears to me that if I have onever file with all related functions (functions from more than one ajax script) it becomes annoying to maintain (cause there will be many slightly different but still similar functions in a big file) while if I do one function file per ajax script, it makes a lot of files with few lines in it. It's a bit of a dilemma. What's the conventional way of doing in this scenario?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I would say explicitly terminating your PHP script like this is a bad idea. Certainly it is very unconventional and will likely confuse other programmers who may one day be maintaining your code.

There's no actual need to exit the script with `die` in the example you posted, since once the interpreter reaches that point it will pass harmlessly over the function definitions and the script will terminate normally at the end of the file, as anyone would expect. So what you're doing is unnecessary.

But it's also actively confusing: Because the script's exit point is now buried in the middle of the file, it will be easy for someone making a quick edit to add code below the `die` and waste time trying to figure out why their changes are having no effect. No programmer is going to *assume* the script is meant to up and die at some random point in its middle.

A professional programmer normally groups function definitions together towards the *top* of a file, ahead of the code that invokes them. This convention dates back to structured-programming languages like Pascal that actually enforced this as a rule, but it makes good sense in general. Think of how people communicate in everyday life: Isn't it confusing when a person starts talking about something before they've told you what it is they're talking about?

Comment: Personally, I think having functions at the top makes the code much more confusing. I like opening a file, seeing the main't code and getting an idea of what's  going on. For instance, in the discussion example, it's the equivalent of someone telling you all his arguments, and then piecing them together so that you understand what he's actually talking about. But if course, I get where you're coming from and then "adding code after die" example already happened to me! So what do you think is the best way of declaring the functions? Is it to use the top declaration, or another file, or else?

Comment: I'd follow convention and define your functions before the code that uses them. Most programs are organized this way, so you'll only benefit from becoming comfortable with reading code written like this. Placing the functions in a separate file makes sense only if they are related to one another in terms of their context or usage and they are used by multiple scripts.